# Why is my code not able to perform insert data into table?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am not able to insert data into a table by using the below code. I am not getting any error, but nothing is inserted into the table. The table has been created successfully by the below code but it is not able to insert the data. Why?

```
DECLARE
table_or_view_does_not_exist exception;
pragma exception_init(table_or_view_does_not_exist,-00942);
d_table varchar2(200);
q_table varchar2(200);
  v_sql   VARCHAR2(4000);
  v_value VARCHAR2(4000);
  v_cur   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN  
DBMS_OUTPUT. ENABLE (buffer_size => NULL);
begin
d_table:='drop table fms_addr_Spcl_Char PURGE';
execute immediate d_table;
exception
when table_or_view_does_not_exist then
null;
end;
----dbms_output.put_line('Table has been dropped');
q_table:='create table fms_addr_Spcl_Char 
         (table_name varchar2(50), 
         column_name varchar2(50),
         spcl_char varchar2(500),
         spcl_char_count varchar2(50))';
         execute immediate q_table;
---dbms_output.put_line('Table has been created');
  FOR r IN (
    select table_name,
           column_name
    from   all_tab_columns
    where  table_name=upper('fms_user_address_book')
    and    OWNER = 'FMS_ADMIN'
  ) loop
    v_sql := 'select "'||r.column_name||'" AS data
              from   "'||r.table_name||'"
              where  regexp_like ("'||r.column_name||'",''[&]'') and zone=''SZ''';
    -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql);
OPEN v_cur FOR v_sql;
    LOOP
      FETCH v_cur INTO v_value;
      EXIT WHEN v_cur%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r.table_name || '.' || r.column_name  || '---->' || v_value||'  '||v_cur%rowcount);
    execute immediate 'insert into fms_addr_Spcl_Char values (:param1,:param2,:param3,:param4)' 
    using r.table_name,r.column_name ,v_value,v_cur%rowcount;
    END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Don't use dynamic SQL for the insert, nor create your table within your procedure. This eliminates dependencies that are important for good programming (as evidenced by your defined exception) and takes out a lot of concurrency mechanisms for dictionary change and hard parsing of the insert. Instead, create your table once (outside of PL/SQL) and leave it alone permanently. Use a normal insert (not within `execute immediate`).  If you must clear the table on each run, do a truncate (inside an `execute immediate`) when you start out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can write your code much simpler, less error prone and faster:

```
create table fms_addr_Spcl_Char 
     (table_name varchar2(50), 
     column_name varchar2(50),
     spcl_char varchar2(500),
     spcl_char_count varchar2(50));

DECLARE
  v_sql   VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN  
execute immediate 'TRUNCATE TABLE fms_addr_Spcl_Char';
  FOR r IN (
    select table_name,
           column_name
    from   all_tab_columns
    where  table_name=upper('fms_user_address_book')
    and    OWNER = 'FMS_ADMIN'
  ) loop
    v_sql := 'INSERT INTO fms_addr_Spcl_Char (table_name, column_name, spcl_char, spcl_char_count)
              select :tableName, :colName, "'||r.column_name||'", ROWNUM
              from   '||r.table_name||'
              where  regexp_like ("'||r.column_name||'", :regex) and zone = :zone';
    execute immediate v_sql USING, table_name, column_name, '&', 'SZ';
END;
```

If you create a `GLOBAL TEMPORARY` table, then the `TRUNCATE` might not be needed either.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that's because there are no rows in xxx table that satisfy conditions, so - nothing has been returned nor inserted.

Sample table that *contains* data you expect (that's the row identified by `ID = 1`):

```
SQL> create table fms_user_address_book as
  2  select 1 id, 'SZ' zone, 'some & value' name from dual union all
  3  select 2   , 'xy & z' , 'another value'     from dual;

Table created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
```

Your code, modified a little bit (changed owner as I don't have the one you do, and I don't feel like creating one):

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2  table_or_view_does_not_exist exception;
  3  pragma exception_init(table_or_view_does_not_exist,-00942);
  4  d_table varchar2(200);
  5  q_table varchar2(200);
  6    v_sql   VARCHAR2(4000);
  7    v_value VARCHAR2(4000);
  8    v_cur   SYS_REFCURSOR;
  9  BEGIN
 10  DBMS_OUTPUT. ENABLE (buffer_size => NULL);
 11  begin
 12  d_table:='drop table fms_addr_Spcl_Char PURGE';
 13  execute immediate d_table;
 14  exception
 15  when table_or_view_does_not_exist then
 16  null;
 17  end;
 18  ----dbms_output.put_line('Table has been dropped');
 19  q_table:='create table fms_addr_Spcl_Char
 20           (table_name varchar2(50),
 21           column_name varchar2(50),
 22           spcl_char varchar2(500),
 23           spcl_char_count varchar2(50))';
 24           execute immediate q_table;
 25  ---dbms_output.put_line('Table has been created');
 26    FOR r IN (
 27      select table_name,
 28             column_name
 29      from   all_tab_columns
 30      where  table_name=upper('fms_user_address_book')
 31      and    OWNER = 'SCOTT'
 32    ) loop
 33      v_sql := 'select "'||r.column_name||'" AS data
 34                from   "'||r.table_name||'"
 35                where  regexp_like ("'||r.column_name||'",''[&]'') and zone=''SZ''';
 36       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql);
 37  OPEN v_cur FOR v_sql;
 38      LOOP
 39        FETCH v_cur INTO v_value;
 40        EXIT WHEN v_cur%NOTFOUND;
 41      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r.table_name || '.' || r.column_name  || '---->' || v_value||'  '||v_cur%rowcount);
 42      execute immediate 'insert into fms_addr_Spcl_Char values (:param1,:param2,:param3,:param4)'
 43      using r.table_name,r.column_name ,v_value,v_cur%rowcount;
 44      END LOOP;
 45      END LOOP;
 46  END;
 47  /
select "ID" AS data
              from   "FMS_USER_ADDRESS_BOOK"

where  regexp_like ("ID",'[&]') and zone='SZ'
select "ZONE" AS data
              from   "FMS_USER_ADDRESS_BOOK"

where  regexp_like ("ZONE",'[&]') and zone='SZ'
select "NAME" AS data
              from   "FMS_USER_ADDRESS_BOOK"

where  regexp_like ("NAME",'[&]') and zone='SZ'
FMS_USER_ADDRESS_BOOK.NAME---->some & value  1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From fms_addr_Spcl_Char;

TABLE_NAME                COLUMN_NAM SPCL_CHAR       SPCL_CHAR_COUNT
------------------------- ---------- --------------- ---------------
FMS_USER_ADDRESS_BOOK     NAME       some & value    1

SQL>
```

Comment: Actually ,it was working , can you please modify my code if i want to change special character & with #  then * then % then | one by one by using dynamic SQL or using varray collection? actually i want to scan whole table with regexp_like("'||r.column_name||'",'[#!$&*%|]') but at the end ,this regexp is not giving exact count in my table with v_cur%rowcount even if i use if statement ,it gives wrong count for &